# Compact embeddings of Sobolev spaces: a counterexample showing the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem is sharp

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Let $U$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^{1}$ boundary.  Let $1 \leq p < n$ and $p^{\ast} = pn/(n-p)$.  Then the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(U)$ is contained $L^{p^{\ast}}(U)$ and there is a constant $C$, depending only on $p$, $n$, and $U$, such that
$$
\|u\|_{L^{p^{*}}(U)} \leq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}
$$
for every $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ (cf. Theorem 2 in Section 5.6.1 of *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans).

The Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem says that $W^{1,p}(U)$ is compactly embedded into $L^{q}(U)$ for every $1 \leq q < p^{*}$.  This means two things:

(i) There is a constant $C$, depending only on $p$, $n$, and $U$, such that
$$
\displaystyle{ \|u\|_{L^q(U)}  \leq  C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)} }
$$
for every $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$.

(ii) Every bounded sequence $(u_k)$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$ has a subsequence $(u_{k_j})$ that converges in $L^q(U)$.

**Is there a standard counterexample that shows we cannot take $q=p^{\ast}$ in the Rellich-Kondrachov Compactness Theorem?**  In other words, I am asking for a sequence $(u_k)$ that is bounded in the $W^{1,p}(U)$ norm but has no convergent subsequence in ${L^{p^{\ast}}(U)}$.  Note that such a sequence would have a subsequence that converges in $L^q(U)$ for every $1 \leq q < p^{\ast}$ but diverges in ${L^{p^{*}}(U)}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the name Kondrashev?

Comment: The Russian is В.И.Кондрашов. Therefore, according with the BGN/PCGN romanization of Russian, the English transliteration should be "Kondrashov". Nevertheless, for some reason, "Rellich-Kondrachov theorem" gets more Google results than  "Rellich-Kondrashov theorem" (small numbers, anyway)

Comment: @PietroMajer that's because before we used the French-based latinization (ш= French ch =English sh).

Answer (score 31):

Yes, there is a standard way. Take any nonzero $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$, with support in a ball, say w.l.o.g $\operatorname{supp}(u)\subset B(0,r)\subset U$, and consider 
$$ u_\epsilon(x):= u\big(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\big)$$
Under this action by dilatations, the $L^q$ norm of $u$ and the $L^{p}$ norm of $\nabla u$ rescale with the same powers exactly for $q=p^*$:
$$ \|u_ \epsilon\| _ q = \epsilon^{n/q} \|u\|_ q$$
$$  \| \nabla u_ \epsilon\|_p = \epsilon^{\frac{n-p}{p}} \|\nabla u\| _ p$$
This means that the normalized family , for all $0 < \epsilon \le 1$,

$$ \epsilon ^ { - \frac {n} {p ^ *} } u \Big( \frac{x} {\epsilon} \Big)  \, , \quad  0 < \epsilon \le r $$

is bounded in $W^{1,p}$, and has a constant non-zero norm in $ L^{p*} $, and of course has no convergent subsequences there for $\epsilon \to 0$, since it converges a.e. to zero. Note also  that it converges to $0 $ in $L^q$  for all $ q <  p^*$, as it has to be.

Comment: In this answer, it is not clear to see why the sequence $\{u_\varepsilon\}_\varepsilon$ has no convergent subsequence in $L^{p^\star}$. Basically, there are two types of lacking the compactness property: Unbounded domains and critical exponents. In both cases, it is more convenient to dilate a "good" function plus a scaling of this function if working in bounded domains.

Comment: @QA Ngô  In fact, $u_\epsilon\to0$  a.e., in $L^{p^*}$, and in $W^{1,p}$, as $\epsilon\to0$. The claim is on the *normalized* family: check the last lines.

Comment: You can find this in Adams, Sobolev Spaces.

Comment: Apologies for coming back to very old material, but do you have any comment on the the answers below which claim that there is something amiss in your answer?

Comment: Actually no comment

Answer (score -2):

This question has cropped up in a work of mine.When the $p^*$ norm is computed without using the gradient value of the sequence,the Gagliardo-Nirenberg 'default condition'1 1-n/p + n/p* = 0
appears to impose a restriction on the sequence index epsilon,since the sequence index disappears.This has the  `effect' that the $W^{1,p}$ bound condition the sequence has to compulsorily verify is ignored and this sounds illogical,specially when the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem tacitly makes use of such a  bound in its proof.On the other hand,since the gradient values of the sequence have to be used in integration to verify the $W^{1,p}$ bound and keeping in mind that there is a formula that expresses a $C^1$ function of compact support in terms of its gradient(this by integration by parts of the fundamental solution of the Laplacian),it is possible to obtain estimates for the $p^*$ norm in terms of the L^infinity norm of the defining test function u and what is more,such an estimate involves positive powers of the sequence index epsilon even though the Gagliardo-Nirenberg default condition is used,showing that the sequence actually converges to zero in p* norm! The actual meaning therefore is that the p* norm computations,one without using the gradient of the sequence and the other using the gradient and its implied value in integration,are different and if forcibly compared,leads to the contradiction that u vanishes identically.We have worked out the proof that relies on nontrivial facts such as strong bounds for the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function.
It is to be noted further that the condition $q < p^*$ is only a sufficient condition to establish the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem by interpolation and there is nothing to support that the theorem can not be established by a procedure that does not require interpolation.
In summary,the counter-example seems vacuous,showing that compactness at p* may still be an open problem!

Comment: In respect of the Question raised by Ànonimous',if only one can,and indeed one should inevitably,give-up using the àpriori given,generic'Lebesgue norm and use instead the gradient
estimated(from a reproducing kernel formula) Lebesgue norm,the dilemma is resolved for good.Indeed by a well known finite measure theoretic result of A.Villani,Rellich-Kondrachov compactness(RK) seen for q<p* is transferred to RK at p* by Cauchy Continuity.Thus any measure of non-compactness at p* has to be zero.The inf.metric on W^(1,p) on the bounded set is incomplete as well in respect of a uniform gauge.