# An inequality with critical Sobolev exponent

Tags: inequalities, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n, n\geq 3$ be a nice bounded domain and $2^*=2n/(n-2)$ the critical Sobolev exponent. One may expect that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists C_\epsilon<\infty$ such that 
$$
\|u\|_{2^*}\leq \epsilon \|\nabla u\|_2+C_\epsilon \|u\|_2, \quad \forall u\in H^1(\Omega).
$$
Due to the lack of  compact embedding from $H^1$ into $L^{2^*}$, the above inequality is indeed not true by the example listed [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81034/).
Now, I wish to make it right by formulating it in a strengthened version as follows: given $p\in (2,2(n+2)/n)$ (or $p\in(2,2^*)$ in the worst case), $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists C_\epsilon<\infty$ such that 
$$
\|u\|_{2^*}\leq \epsilon (\|\nabla u\|_2+\|u\|_p^{p/2})+C_\epsilon(1+ \|u\|_2), \quad \forall u\in H^1(\Omega).   \tag{MCIS}
$$
I tried the example listed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81034/), which does not give a counterexample. Also, arguing by contradiction seems not to work. Any help to prove or disprove (MCIS) is greatly acknowledged.

Comment: For the example Pietro gave, doesn't $\|v_\epsilon\|_p$ for $p < 2^*$ (where $v_\epsilon = \epsilon^{-n/2^*} u(x / \epsilon)$) go to zero for $\epsilon \to 0$? How is adding $\|u\|_p^{p/2}$ supposed to help? (With the $\epsilon$ in front it can only help if it diverges...)

Comment: @Wille Wong, yeah, $\|v_\epsilon\|_p\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ for $p<2^*$. The large constant term $C_\epsilon$ may help in this case. While, in the otherwise case, $\|u\|_p$ may contribute!

Answer (score 1):

Start with Pietro's example in the linked question. Fix $u$. Define 
$$ v_{\delta,M} = M\delta^{-n/2^*} u(x/\delta) $$
We know that $\|\nabla v_{\delta,M}\|_2 = M\|\nabla u\|_2$ and $\|v_{\delta,M}\|_{2^*} = M\|u\|_{2^*}$. Choose $\epsilon < \frac12 (\|u\|_{2^*} / \|\nabla u\|_2 )$.

We also know that for $M$ fixed, as $\delta \to 0$ we have that $\|u\|_p \to 0$ in the range of $p$ you allow.

Now, let $\Lambda > 0$ be arbitrary. We show that for every fixed $\Lambda$ there exists $\delta$ and $M$ such that 
$$ \|v_{\delta,M} \|_{2^*} > \epsilon (\|\nabla v_{\delta,M}\|_2 + \|v_{\delta,M}\|_p^{p/2} ) + \Lambda (1 + \|v_{\delta,M}\|_2) $$
which will disprove your desired inequality.

By our choice of small $\epsilon$, it suffices to prove
$$ \frac12 \|v_{\delta,M} \|_{2^*} = \frac{M}{2} \|u\|_{2^*} > \epsilon \|v_{\delta,M}\|_{p}^{p/2} + \Lambda + \Lambda \|v_{\delta,M}\|_2 = \epsilon M \|v_{\delta,1}\|_p^{p/2} + \Lambda M \|v_{\delta,1}\|_2 + \Lambda $$

First choose $M$ sufficiently large that 
$$ \frac{M}{4} \|u\|_{2^*} > \Lambda $$
then choose $\delta$ sufficiently small so that the first two terms on the right hand side of the desired inequality is negligible.

Comment: thank you for your cute observation! This once again shows the compact embedding is vital to have $\epsilon$ in front of the highest order term.