# Embeddings of Sobolev spaces on the unit disk

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is the space $W^{2,p}(\mathbf{U})$, compactly embedded to $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbf{U})$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is the unit disk.

Comment: By Rellich-Kondrachov yes if $p>2$.

Comment: And no for $p\le2$: you can do the same construction here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81034/compact-embeddings-of-sobolev-spaces-a-counterexample-showing-the-rellich-kondr/81044#81044

Comment: For a non-zero smooth function $f$ with compact support in $U$ consider $f_\epsilon(x):={\epsilon}f({x\over\epsilon})$. It converges to zero uniformly for $\epsilon\to0$, and it has bounded $W^{2,2}$-norm (because $\| D^2 f_\epsilon\|_{2}=\|D^2 f\|_{2}$ and $\|f_\epsilon\|_{1,2}=o(1)$, so it converges to $0$ also weakly $W^{2,2}$. But it has constant non-zero $\|\nabla f_\epsilon\|_{\infty}=\|\nabla f\|_{\infty}$ so no subsequence can converge in $W^{1,\infty}$ norm .